# Meaning of „Dass, wer in der CDU-Führung sagt, … nicht beachtet“

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english

This sentence is the beginning of an [article in Frankfurter Allgemeine](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/cdu-und-afd-keine-alternative-13156975.html):

> Dass, wer in der CDU-Führung sagt, die „Alternative für Deutschland“ (AfD) sei zu ignorieren, diese auch tatsächlich nicht beachtet, glauben mutmaßlich selbst diejenigen in der CDU nicht, die ihre Parteispitze deswegen kritisieren.

So, it is presumed that the fact "Dass … beachtet" is not believed even by those in the CDU, who criticize the party leadership because of that.

But what does the part  "Dass … beachtet" mean? What does "wer in der CDU-Führung sagt" mean, and what does "diese" refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a complicated sentence. Freely translated, it means:

Not even those members of the CDU who criticize their party leadership for ignoring the AfD are likely to believe that CDU leaders who say that the AfD must be ignored actually do not pay attention to it.

Comment: Good translation, except that "not paying attention" doesn't seem a good choice, here. Btw., it's pretty much 1:1 (sentence structure excluded, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

It is not "Dass ... beachtet", but "Dass ... glauben". But the sentence is really hard to read even for native german speakers. Here is a try to reorder the sentence:

Dass diejenigen in der CDU-Führung, die sagen, die "Alternative für Deutschland" (AfD) sei zu ignorieren, die AfD auch tatsächlich nicht beachten, glauben mutmaßlich selbst diejenigen in der CDU nicht, die ihre Parteispitze deswegen kritisieren.

Comment: Your version has a subtle semantical difference to the original. It makes believe the whole _CDU-Führung_ wanted to ignore the AfD, while the original only states that some members of it say so.

Answer (score 1):

> What does "wer in der CDU-Führung sagt" mean?

those members of the CDU leadership who say

> What does "diese" refer to?

die "Alternative für Deutschland" (AfD)

> What does the part "Dass ... beachtet" mean?

As hellcode already said: this is the wrong pair. The whole phrase between "Dass" and "glauben" is the object of the main clause - it is what some members of the CDU do not believe. These CDU members are the subject, which is further specified by another subordinate clause: members who criticise their leadership for something, and this "something" is given by reference ("deswegen") as the statements mentioned in the beginning ("say to ignore the AfD").

Ingmar already gave a fine translation of the complete sentence (that IMHO retains the complexity and hard-to-read style of the original).

Answer (score 1):

**Object structure**

It's weird, but the object is a relative clause, with everything between *dass* and *diese* as its subject.

```
Dass, wer in der CDU-Führung sagt,     (short for 'Dass der, der in der CDU-Führung sagt, ...')  
    die AfD sei zu ignorieren,         (infinitive group specifying 'sagt')
diese auch tatsächlich nicht beachtet, ('beachtet' is the verb belonging to 'dass')
```

**Sentence structure**

```
    Dass, wer in der CDU-Führung sagt,           |              
        die AfD sei zu ignorieren,               | (all of this is the object for [nicht] glauben)  
    diese auch tatsächlich nicht beachtet,       | 

glauben mutmaßlich selbst diejenigen in der CDU nicht, (main clause)

   die ihre Parteispitze deswegen kritisieren. (relative clause describing 'diejenigen')
```

**Simplified:**

Dass die CDU-Führung die AfD nicht beachtet, glauben nicht mal die, die die Führung wegen des Nichtbeachtens kritisieren.

**Meaning**

Those party members, who tell the party leadership *It is not smart to ignore them*, know that the leadership actually doesn't ignore them.

(Between the lines: their criticism is put on, they just want to have something to say.)

Answer (score 1):

Extremely close to the original (but no idiomatic English):

> That, whoever says in the CDU leadership that the AfD is to be
>   ignored, actually ignores them, too, is probably not even believed by
>   those in the CDU who criticize their party leadership for that.

If you turn this structure around somewhat, you arrive at [Ingmar's translation](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15943/401).